# How to store strings in xml in Matlab to read it from opencv

Tags: xml, matlab, opencv

I am converting my mat file to an xml file to read it in opencv. I was able to read the xml having double type but I can't read the string. How can I store the string type to xml so that opencv can read and store it in a Matrix or vector whichever is possible.

The color_details.name contains data like: blue red yellow etc.

My code in matlab to conver in xml is:

```
load('color.mat');

[Row,Col]=size(color_details);
    docNode=com.mathworks.xml.XMLUtils.createDocument('opencv_storage');
    docRootNode = docNode.getDocumentElement;
    orientation=docNode.createElement('color_details_name');
    orientation.setAttribute('type_id','opencv-matrix');
    docRootNode.appendChild(orientation);
    rows=docNode.createElement('rows');
    rows.appendChild(docNode.createTextNode(num2str(Row)));
    orientation.appendChild(rows);
    cols=docNode.createElement('cols');
    cols.appendChild(docNode.createTextNode(num2str(Col)));
    orientation.appendChild(cols);
    dt=docNode.createElement('dt');
    dt.appendChild(docNode.createTextNode('d')); //not sure what to write here
    orientation.appendChild(dt);
      data=docNode.createElement('data');

for i=1:Row
    for j=1:Col
   mapdata=(color_details(i,j).name);
   data.appendChild(docNode.createTextNode(mapdata));
      data.appendChild(docNode.createTextNode(' '));

    end
end
    orientation.appendChild(data);
    orientation_save_name=['color_details_name.xml' ];
     xmlwrite(orientation_save_name,docNode);
     edit(orientation_save_name);
```

My code in opencv to read is this::

```
string filename = "color_details_name.xml";

Mat colors;
FileStorage fs;
    fs.open(filename, FileStorage::READ);

    if (fs.isOpened())
    {
        cout<<"File is opened\n";
    }

    fs["color_details_name"] >> colors;

    cout<<colors<<endl;
    fs.release();
```

But the above code give some type error. How can I solve this?

Comment: unspecified error in cvRead. The node does not represent a cv object. Becuase I think the mat cannot store string type? And the type specified is double in xml.

Answer (score 0):

How I use to create data is like that :

```
M = eye(3);
reshaped = reshape(M,1,size(M,1)*size(M,2));
charM = num2str(reshaped);

data.appendChild(docNode.createTextNode(sprintf('%s',charM)));
```

OpenCV save data as `char` when you use xmlread. So I save it same way. I create an `1xN` array and transform in string.

You can optimize that code to trim space and get smaller xml file, else they gonna be huge if you have big matrix.